# UAV simulation in MATLAB for target tracking

Tags: matlab, simulink, robotics

My objective is to track a moving target on ground by an UAV and this simulation is to be done in MATLAB. I have written code for developing Urban environment plot and also put a moving point in the plot(for the target).Now for the UAV I need to implement certain guidance laws(is what I understand from resources on the Internet).So how should I proceed with it?Will I be able to write code for that also?Or should I develop a simulink model and integrate my previous code as well?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to implement a simulation either with Matlab or Simulink. Which is more fit will depend on the approach you decide to take. Maybe you should decide what motion planning algorithm to implement before jumping into implementation. Wikipedia has a list of common algorithms:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_planning#Algorithms